# Möbius tranformation are continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We define a Möbius transformation through:
$$z\rightarrow \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, ad-bc\neq0, a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{C}$$
and extend to the Riemann sphere as follows: if $c=0$, $T(\infty)=\infty$, and if $c\neq0$, $T(\infty)=a/c$ and $T(-d/c)=\infty$.
Show that the Möbius transformations are continuous in that area with the chordal metric.
We define the chordal metric thus:
$$d_{c}(z_{1},z_{2})=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2|z_{1}-z_{2}|}{\sqrt{1+|z_{1}|^2}\sqrt{1+|z_{2}|^2}}& \text{if $z_{1},\,z_{2}\neq \infty$}\\
\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+|z_{1}|^2}} & \text{if $z_{2}= \infty$.}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: For an example of why I (and now Daniel) changed your post, consider $a=c=d=1$ and $b=-1.$ Then $ad-bc\ne0,$ but $$\frac{az-b}{cz+d}=\frac{z+1}{z+1}$$ is **not** a Mobius transformation, as we require these to be one-to-one.

Comment: Who, where and why require Moebius Transformations to be one-to-one? I never heard of that conditions...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I've always seen them defined thus, e.g. so that they form the group $PGL(2,\mathbb C) =$ conformal automorphisms of the sphere.

Comment: I ask again for links/books where it is required a linear transformation is $\,1-1\,$ in order to be called Moebius transformation, @AnthonyCarapetis  . All the definitions I know *never* require such a thing, but hey: I could be wrong.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Wikipedia and Jost's "Compact Riemann Surfaces" agree with me... I haven't any other books at hand right now. Of course it's just a matter of semantics for this particular question - the only singular transformations of this form are the constant maps which are obviously also continuous.

Comment: I'm reading Wiki and I can't see such *requirement* , @AnthonyCarapetis . Of course, it **follows** from the definition and condition $\,ad-bc\neq 0\,$, but it is not, imo, within the definition (I have not Jost's book, though). This came because of Cameron's comment that $\,\frac{z+1}{z+1}\,$ is not a Moebius Tr. because "...as we require these to be one-to-one", whereas I'd say the true reason *from definition* the above is not a Moebius Tr. is because $\,ad-bc=0\,$: why would we want to unnecessarily mention a characteristic that follows from the definition?

Comment: [Continuation] We can say (and see) that from definition $$\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{aw+b}{cw+d}\iff (ad-bc)(z-w)=0\implies z=w$$since, of course, $ad-bc\neq0\,$ **as required in the definition** .I think things like this one can cause confusion among students, in particular among beginning ones.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Ah, I was conflating "1-1" with $ad-bc\ne 0$. I agree that it would be silly to include both conditions in the definition when either follows from the other.