# Möbius tranformation

Tags: complex-numbers, linear-fractional-transformation

We define a Möbius transformation through:
$$z\rightarrow \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, ad-bc\neq0, a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{C}$$
and extend to the Riemann sphere as follows: if $c=0$, $T(\infty)=\infty$, and if $c\neq0$, $T(\infty)=a/c$ and $T(-d/c)=\infty$.
Show that the Möbius transformations are continuous in that area with the chordal metric.
We define the chordal metric thus:
$$d_{c}(z_{1},z_{2})=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2|z_{1}-z_{2}|}{\sqrt{1+|z_{1}|^2}\sqrt{1+|z_{2}|^2}}& \text{if $z_{1},\,z_{2}\neq \infty$}\\
\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+|z_{1}|^2}} & \text{if $z_{2}= \infty$.}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480883/mobius-tranformation-are-continuous

Comment: Both attend the same class? (Ernesto and user92517)

Comment: This is a metric on a space consisting of a plane with a point at infinity adjoined.  Let $z=p(x)$ be a stereographdic projection from a sphere onto that space (or is that the inverse of a stereographic projection?), and consider the metric $D(x_1,x_2)=d_c(p(x_1),p(x_2))$.  Consider what that metric on the sphere looks like.  E.g. is it invariant under rotations?  And use the fact that the stereographic projection is a continuous function.